# jquery-ui autocomplete ajax, isusse in succes

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a one autocomplete element in my page, i use json to request data, but i cant see the UI.

I made test in past, with default fuctionaly

```
 $(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
 });
```

But, **i chage the structure of my data**

```
 $(function () {
     var availableTags = [
      {"label":"one label", "value":"one value", "id":1},
      {"label":"2 label", "value":"2", "id":2},
      {"label":"3 label", "value":"3", "id":3},
      {"label":"4 label", "value":"etc", "id":4}
        ];
     $("#tags").autocomplete({
         source: availableTags,
         select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id_element').val(ui.item.id);//for example
  }
     });
 });
```

I did this to work with the event select, now I want to get data from json

```
 $("#inputskills").autocomplete({
         source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + getPathStr() + '/Skills/1?term='+request.term,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(item));
            alert(item.value+' - '+item.label+ ' - ' + item.id );
                return{
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.id
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
select .....
```

my service return correct data, when i show data with alert function, is correct data, but, autocomplete no work, no sohw any data, i tried change return code, but I could not make it work

i change to

```
  return {
     label: item.label,
     id: item.id,
     value: item.value
  }
```

or

```
 return item;
```

but still I can not, help me please.

Comment: Are you getting some error ?

Comment: And you're sure that `alert(item.value+' - '+item.label+ ' - ' + item.id );` actually happened with expected data?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann no, i no get a error.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, and  `alert(JSON.stringify(item));` sohw correct data

Comment: You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. The messages will arrive in your browser's JavaScript console, and it's _much_ nicer for debugging.